# Enterprise Architect version control settings are not saved

Tags: enterprise-architect

I use Enterprise Architect 933 and I have a problem with the version control settings (subversion). When I open an .eap file, it prompts me to configure the version control settings, which i do and then i can work normally. When I close and reopen the file, it prompts me again, like if the settings were not saved at all. 
What is going wrong or what do I have to do?

Regards
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the integrated Baselines?
The version control settings are, in my opinion, not the very best solution.

Even when there are not many people in your project, i think with baselines you could work better and faster. 
Or you export on XMI 2.1 and you hold this file under version control. 
Works also because since XMI 2 it holds graphical information.

So only export in Xmi 2.x!